# What entity should entity_id be joined on?

Tags: commerce, entities, database

I'm writing a complex custom query to get order information from a Drupal Commerce install for export.

The table `field_data_commerce_customer_address` has a column `entity_id.` I've tried to join that field on `order_id`, but my results are incorrect. It doesn't match to user id... hmm.

What field should I join `entity_id` on?

And, more generally, is there a drupal entity informational function that would tell me what columns should be joined to what? Or a master entity table, or anything? Some central location that would tell me things like this so I don't have to dig around?

Looking around the database and googling but haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entity_id` is the ID of the Commerce customer profile (which you can find in the `commerce_customer_profile` table).

This makes more sense when you look at the `type` column in the same field table, as it will likely be one of "shipping" or "billing", the default bundles available to the profile entity type.

Profile entities have a `uid`, which links back to the related user.

So if you're building a manual query, and want to involve the user id, you also need to join in `commerce_customer_profile` on `commerce_customer_profile.profile_id = field_data_commerce_customer_address.entity_id`. You'll then be able to use `commerce_customer_profile.uid` for further joins/constraints.

Answer (score 2):

The customer addresses are linked to the user, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/121356/2322 for more details on this, so you've got an order that references a customer profile and this references a user.

It doesn't show this part, but find a more complete description about the commerce entities in this documentation page: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products

[image]

In any case, I'd definitely use [Entity Field Query](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) for this, it will save you from digging in the database and it will give you a more consistent way to access your data.

Comment: In this case, I can't use Entity Field Query because of the number of joins I have to do. 8 joins in and I wish I could, though. There's a reason why you don't get Drupal Commerce data straight out of the database.

Answer (score 1):

It's a field table, so, in principle, *any* entity bundle could use use the field and store data to it. The entity_type column should give you the type of entity. If it is "node", then you need to join with the node table on nid, etc.